# Simple question , just observe a thing

Tags: complex-numbers

$x = a + bw + cw^2 , y = aw + bw^2 + c , z = aw^2 + b + cw$

Find the value of $ \dfrac{x^2}{yz} + \dfrac{y^2}{xz} + \dfrac{z^2}{xy}$

Note - Here **w** is one of the roots of unity.

I know the answer but want to see other's method how do they do it

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y,z$ be the roots of the cubic equation $$p(r)=r^3+sr^2+tr+u=0$$

Note that $u=-xyz$ and $s=x+y+z=0$

Now $$0=p(x)+p(y)+p(z)=(x^3+y^3+z^3)+t(x+y+z)+3u=(x^3+y^3+z^3)-3xyz$$

From which we have $$3xyz=x^3+y^3+z^3$$ and divide by $xyz$.

Comment: Good but not that much good as mine's should I post mine's solution?